# Drop text at caret position in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to drop any html (from any source page) into a contenteditable div, while converting it to plain text, however I am unable to insert the result text at caret position.

I tried using `window.getSelection()` method but it does not return the drop caret position.

Here is where I am stuck at:

```js
drop = function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(data);
  
  e.target.appendChild(textnode); // I want this to be inserted at caret position
  e.target.normalize();

  return false;

}
```

```css
 div {border: 1px solid #000;padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<h3>Source</h3>
<div contenteditable>
  <span style="color:#3366bb">Dummy <b>formatted</b> text</span>
</div>

<h3>Target div</h3>
<div contenteditable ondrop="drop(event)">
  Drag and drop any formatted text in the middle of <i>this</i> paragraph
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See this. It is very close to your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/jkLhfzr8/

Comment: Thanks Alireza, I've seen that one but it relies on source element so it wouldn't work in my case